# jboss-common-core maven dependencies

Tags: maven, jboss, dependencies

Does anyone know repositories where we can download jboss-common-core and all its dependencies. The dependencies are the ones which cant be found.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jboss/jboss-common-core/2.0.4.GA and https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/jboss/jboss-common-core/2.0.4.GA/ .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's in Maven Central:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjboss%7Cjboss-common-core%7C2.0.4.GA%7Cjar

Comment: Problem is its unable to find its dependencies. Here is the log when i try to build my project.

http://pastebin.com/0c8aASBu

Answer (score 0):

It is probably way too late to be answering this as it's now 2016, but this may help someone else.

To get a minimalist version of that specific jar/pom, you can get it from here:

https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone

Interestingly enough, if you try to get it from other repos, the pom file is different and has many more dependencies which can't be found as mentioned above.

Currently, I am using the minimalist one and it is working - but If I look at several other repos, they all have the longer, harder to resolve pom...so I think it may be dangerous to use the minimalist one.

Hope this helps someone out there.